# List and for in the Power BI

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, powerbi, conditional-statements

I have a column "answers" in my data whose values can be a,b,c up to the letter z. I want to create a "conditional" column that would always result in 1 when the row result equals my list of correct answers ={a,d,f,g,j). I did it with the switch, but as this list can change, adding more letters, it is not automatic, being necessary for me to manually insert each letter that represents the answer into the switch. Is it possible to use a "for" inside power BI so that it automates this?
thought about:

list={a,d,f,g,j)
For k in list:
if responses [k]=list:
1;
else:0

I don't know how to structure this in the context of Dax or M language

Comment: What does the data in your `Answers` column look like?

Comment: Please provide clear start and expected results for your data as this is difficult to understand. Do you want a solution in M or DAX?